# Problem linking against pcap.h

Tags: compiling, gcc, libpcap

I am trying to compile ethping
Here is the command that gets issued via make:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -ggdb -g -O2 -lpcap  -o ethping ethping.o ieee8021ag.o dot1ag_eth.o
```

I now get this error message:

```
/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:65: undefined reference to `pcap_breakloop'
```

Indicating that it cannot find the `pcap.h`.

So I type:

```
root:src# whereis pcap.h
pcap: /usr/include/pcap.h /usr/include/pcap /usr/share/man/man3/pcap.3pcap.gz
root:src# 



root:src# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/include
```

And the `/usr/include` is definitely in my path.

The only thing that might be an issue is that `/usr/include/pcap.h` is a stub file that does and include of `pcap/pcap.h`.

```
/*
 * For backwards compatibility.
 *
 * Note to OS vendors: do NOT get rid of this file!  Many applications
 * expect to be able to include <pcap.h>, and at least some of them
 * go through contortions in their configure scripts to try to detect
 * OSes that have "helpfully" moved pcap.h to <pcap/pcap.h> without
 * leaving behind a <pcap.h> file.
 */
#include <pcap/pcap.h>
```

So in `/usr/include/pcap/pcap.h` is the actual file contents with those definitions present.

Comment: **Header files are not libraries**. Undefined references are *link-time errors*, they mean you are either missing a library directive on the gcc command line, or (more likely in this case) are listing libraries in the wrong order (i.e. `-lpcap` must be to the right of object files that depend on its symbols).

Comment: I.e., no, the error does *not* indicate that it could not find pcap.h; if it couldn't find pcap.h, it would have said so.  It indicates that, for some reason, it couldn't find `pcap_breakloop()` in libpcap; what does the command `tcpdump -h` print?

Comment: root:dot1ag-utils-master# tcpdump -h
tcpdump version 4.5.1
libpcap version 1.5.3

Comment: aaaaggghhh steeldriver you had it right I moved -lpcap to the end and it worked!gcc -Wall -Werror -ggdb -g -O2  -I /usr/include/pcap -o ethping ethping.o ieee8021ag.o dot1ag_eth.o -lpcap

Answer (score 1):

You have to install not only the header files, but the libraries also. These are the packages ending in `-dev`, so in this case:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

By the way, this is a metapackage, which will install `libpcap0.8-dev` package.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the libpcap-dev is installed as well allready when I am getting the error